# Sql Server Actualizar Columna desde otra tabla

Tags: sql-server

Tengo una tabla, donde necesito actualizar un dato que esta en otra tabla de acuerdo a una llave, pero no me actualiza correctamente los datos.

```
Update KM_ficha set FichaActual = rtrim(ltrim(B.Idhistorial))
from KM_ficha A, [dbo].[base datos cliente] B
where ltrim(rtrim(A.rut)) = ltrim(rtrim(B.rut))
```

Sin embargo, no se actualiza el dato en la columna de la tabla A.
Qué estoy haciendo mal??

se me paso un detalle. la tabla B, tiene registros repetidos, y necesito uopdatear al mas actual en base a Idhistorial

Comment: Cuál es el campo que en la **tabla B** que especifica el último registro? Una **fecha**? Un **id**?

Comment: Hola, muchas gracias por tu ayuda. El campo que identifica el ultimo registro es un numerico que se llama iddatoscliente.

Comment: Edite la respuesta... no había considerado los registros repetidos :)

Comment: _¿updatear?_ :o :o :o

Answer (score 1):

Prueba realizando un `JOIN` para actualización de la siguiente forma:

```
UPDATE t1 SET t1.columna = (SELECT TOP 1 columna FROM tabla2 ORDER BY columna DESC)
FROM tabla1 t1 JOIN tabla2 t2 ON t1.columna = t2.columna
```

De esta forma te aseguras de estar enlazando ambas tablas y actualizando las columnas que necesitas.

Nos comentas :)

Answer (score 1):

Si lo haces por separado, de la siguiente forma:

1- Obtener el registro más actual en una tabla derivada.

2- Y luego hacer el update con los datos de la tabla derivada.

```
Update f set f.FichaActual = t.Idhistorial
from KM_ficha f
inner join (
    select ltrim(rtrim(A.rut)) as rut, max(rtrim(ltrim(B.Idhistorial))) as Idhistorial
    from KM_ficha A
    join [dbo].[base datos cliente] B
    on ltrim(rtrim(A.rut)) = ltrim(rtrim(B.rut))
    group by ltrim(rtrim(A.rut))
)t
on ltrim(rtrim(f.rut)) = t.rut
```

Comment: Creo que no es necesario hacer el join a `KM_ficha` dentro de la tabla derivada. Si hay pocos registros no importa, pero si fueran muchos puede hacer la diferencia.