# Actualizar datos desde otra tabla

Tags: sql-server

Estoy tratando de actualizar un dato mediante un calculo para obtener el porcentaje correcto eh intentado con este script pero actualiza otro dato es como si copiara de la columna porcentajeFisico

```sql
update TB_PLANILLA set PORCENTAJE_AVANCE_FINANCIERO = ((AVANCE_PLANILLA * 100 )/TC.MONTO_CONTRATO)
from TB_PLANILLA TP INNER JOIN TB_CONTRATO TC ON TC.ID_CONTRATO=TP.ID_CONTRATO
WHERE TC.ID_CONTRATO='D1AE3167-C0AD-4E52-8BB0-B32D24795856'
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

estas son las dos tablas

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Sql Server Actualizar Columna desde otra tabla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/224383/sql-server-actualizar-columna-desde-otra-tabla)

Answer (score 0):

Para hacer el `UPDATE` usando `INNER JOIN` puedes hacerlo así:

```
UPDATE TP 
SET PORCENTAJE_AVANCE_FINANCIERO = (AVANCE_PLANILLA * 100 )/CONVERT(FLOAT,TC.MONTO_CONTRATO)
FROM TB_PLANILLA TP 
INNER JOIN TB_CONTRATO TC ON TP.ID_CONTRATO = TC.ID_CONTRATO
WHERE TC.ID_CONTRATO='D1AE3167-C0AD-4E52-8BB0-B32D24795856'
```

Convierto a `FLOAT` el valor de la división ya que no sé qué tipo de dato es `TC.MONTO_CONTRATO`, en caso que sea entero no te mostrará decimales, pero con el `CONVERT` debería funcionar.